How to dynamically import CSS based on server side prop?
I have a scenario whereby I must decide during runtime which global CSS file to load/import into my app.
Suppose following global CSS files which set up brand-specific variable values:
src/css/brand-a.css
src/css/brand-b.css

Example of contents (/src/css/brand-a.css):
:root {
  @mixin theme-brand-a; // theme-brand-a is a mixin sourcing global variables for brand-a
}

Note that the CSS must undergo preprocessing, so pre-building under /public/css/<brand>.css is not an option.
Root app file src/pages/_app.tsx:
type OwnPageProps = {
  brand: "a" | "b"
};

const MainApp = ({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps<OwnPageProps>) => {
      const { brand } = pageProps;
      // Need to import brand-specific css
      return   <Component {...pageProps} />
}


Attempt 1:
import from "src/css/brand-a.css"
import from "src/css/brand-b.css"

CSS results in one huge style.css with global styles overwriting each other

Attempt 2 (trick the next/dynamic to load global as module):
src/components/CssLoaderBrandA.tsx
src/components/CssLoaderBrandA.module.css
src/components/CssLoaderBrandB.tsx
src/components/CssLoaderBrandB.module.css
src/components/CssLoader.tsx

Example of CssLoaderBrandA.ts:
import React from 'react';
import './CssLoaderBrandA.module.css';

const CssLoaderBrandA = () => <p />;

export default CssLoaderBrandA;

Example of src/components/CssLoader.tsx:
export const CssLoader = ({ brand }: CssLoaderProps) => {
  switch (brand) {
    case 'A':
      dynamic(() => import('./CssLoaderBrandA'));
      break;
    case 'B':
    default:
      dynamic(() => import('./CssLoaderBrandB'));
      break;
  }
  return <p />;
};

Example of src/pages/_app.tsx
const MainApp = ({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps<OwnPageProps>) => {
      const { brand } = pageProps;
      // Need to import brand-specific css
      return  <>
            <CssLoader brand={brand} />
            <Component {...pageProps} />
      </>
}

Syntax error: Selector ":root" is not pure (pure selectors must contain at least one local class or id)

Attempt 3:
Alter Webpack to remove all CSS/SASS/SCSS loaders and rules and define own chunks for CSS and load them as 'asset/resource'
The CSS gets generated under .next/server/static/css/brand-a.css and any imports give 404 for the generated file.


How do I please Next.js to allow me dynamically to import the CSS?
